# FLRW metric derivation

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, tensor-calculus

How do I get from  the metric for a 3-space of constant curvature $$d\sigma^2 = \frac {dr^2} {1-Kr^2} + r^2 (d\theta^2 + sin^2\theta d\phi^2)$$ to a conformally flat form
$$d\sigma^2=(1+\frac 1 4 K\bar r^2)^{-2} (d\bar r^2 +\bar r^2(d\theta^2+sin^2\theta d\phi^2))  $$
by introducing a new radial parameter $\bar r$ related to r by $$r=1/(1+\frac 1 4 K\bar r^2) $$

I've started by finding the derivative of the radial parameter $d\bar r^2$ , I then substituted this in alongside replacing $r^2$ with the new parameter, however I can't seem to get to the required form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome!

By comparison of the $r^2d\Omega_2^2$-term, the change in the radial coordinate is rather:
$$r = \frac{\bar{r}}{1+K\bar{r}^2/4}$$
(Maybe you were missing $\bar{r}$ in the enumerator.)
Hence,
$$dr = \frac{1-K\bar{r}^2/4}{(1+K\bar{r}^2/4)^2}d\bar{r}$$
and
$$1-Kr^2 = \frac{(1-K\bar{r}^2/4)^2}{(1+K\bar{r}^2/4)^2}$$
This should help.

Comment: Hi @psm, thanks for the answer and spotting that typo, I'm almost there but still stuck with one bit, how do I eliminate the $(1-K \bar r^2 /4)^2$ term to get to the final form?

Comment: You simply need to compute $(1-Kr^2)^{-1}dr^2$ using my expressions from above. Then the factor $(1-K\bar{r}^2/4)^2$ cancels out.